# How do I make a website that can search google?

Tags: google-search

How do I make a website search google, and then return the resulting URLs to the page without taking the user to google?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look on google custom search api

http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html

Comment: Okay, so how did they make a website like this? http://cattuong.net/

Answer (score -1):

What you would normally do in this situation is to employ an API provided by the vendor of the service you wish to consume or present to your customers; but AFAIK Google provides no API for searches, considering the fact that, by and large, searches is what Google *Does™*.

You could of course submit regular HTTP searches to http://google.com and scrape the resulting HTML for the results; but that method is extremely liable to breakage if they change their markup; and you risk getting reamed by Google's legal team.

Reamed hard.

**Edit:** Re: API I stand corrected; it appears you actually have a choice: Pay out your nose, or risk breakage and reaming.

Comment: Okay, so how did they make a website like this? http://cattuong.net/

Comment: @Jacob: Hard to tell without the code of the site in question; but I'm guessing that they probably used the search-and-scrape approach. In for a penny, in for a pound and all that.

Comment: @Wiliham Totland Well how do I do a search-and-scrape approach?

Comment: @Jacob: You HTTP GET some search URL from google, run the resulting HTML through a parser, and extract the URLs from the result links.